# How to statically assert an object can't be moved

Tags: c++, containers, static-assert

For an implementation of a container class that keeps raw pointers to objects (intended for computing and enumerating subsets of objects temporarily), I want to statically assert that the objects pointed to can't be moved to assure that pointers remain valid at least for the lifetime of the objects.

For example, if the objects pointed to are moveable and live in a vector, they might move when the vector grows or reorganizes.

Weak pointers would basically do the job, but requiring all objects to be shared is overkill for the purpose. I also want to iterate the container without checking for null pointers, especially as the number of objects in it is an important information.

One of the following conditions need to be met:

**A)** Objects live on the heap (provided they are not deleted before the container).

**B)** Objects live on the stack (provided container lives in the same scope or a nested scope).

**C)** Objects can't be moved according to class definition (provided they live in the same or a higher scope).

Case C can be verified with `std::is_move_constructible` and the likes, although I'm not sure if that suffices. Is there also a way to assert A and B?

Comment: For C), I think you should use `std::is_move_assignable`  with `std::is_move_constructible`

For A) and B), it seems not possible to me, I don't know any function that do that

Comment: Even if you make sure that the object can't be moved, you still don't control when the object is destroyed. Since you need to trust the owner of the object anyway that it will make sure the object outlives your pointer, I think trusting it to not perform a move (which typically would be followed by destruction of the original anyway) isn't that big of a problem.

Comment: A) and B) are impossible.

Comment: Your objects can still move if a vector reallocates when those objects are copyable. 
So isn't your real requirement, don't modify data (change vectors) while you are working on it? Seems like multithreading is involved.